# Code coverage using Jacoco having application code base and Test code base in different repository

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have requirement of finding code coverage using JACOCO having application code base and Test code base in different repository. various Examples provided details about having application code base and Test code base in same repository. Application has been written in Hibernate and Test being written using Test Ng with Java. 
Looking for some input on this .

Comment: what exactly you would like people to help you?

Comment: Looking for how to achieve it. How to make Jacoco to take application code from remote repository and where can i specify that ? Below is the dependency to add in pom.xml but i dont see where to specify that application code is in remote repsitory

Comment: i m referring to pom.xml in https://www.mkyong.com/maven/jacoco-java-code-coverage-maven-example/